# 1:x relationships instead of 1:n relationships

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I'd like to know how one would model a 1:x relationship, where x is not 'many', but a fixed number, in an E-R data model. A simplified theoretical example:

Entities
HOUSE
ROOM

There's a 1:n relationship between HOUSE and ROOM, but what if we want to add that a house must have between one and eight rooms.

Another contrived, more complex and slightly different example:

Entities
HOUSE
ROOM
PARENT
CHILD

Relationships
HOUSE 1:n ROOM
PARENT 1:n CHILD
HOUSE 1:1 PARENT - A parent must own exactly one house and a house must be owned by exactly one parent

How do we add to this the following: The number of rooms in a house must be equal to the number of children the house's owner has?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a database we can implement such rules as *constraints*.

In SQL a CHECK constraint for your rule might be:

```
CHECK NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT MAX(house.owner) parent, COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM house, room
  WHERE house.house_id = room.house_id
  GROUP BY house_id
  EXCEPT
  SELECT parent, COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM child
  GROUP BY parent
)
```

This is ISO Standard SQL but not all SQL DBMSs support the ability to put subqueries in constraints. Such a constraint typically has to apply to only one of the tables. SQL DBMSs usually only allow inserts to one table at once and therefore if you applied similar constraints on both the house *and* child tables it would be impossible to add new houses or children because the constraint would be broken by the first insert. A possible workaround is to disable the constraint temporarily. Some DBMSs support the concept of "deferred" (temporarily disabled) constraints for this purpose.

In ER modelling there is no standard notation for constraints in general. Only certain very simple rules can be represented diagrammatically. More complex rules are sometimes added as text annotations or left out of ER diagrams altogether.

If it's important to you to be able to model such rules formally then don't rely on ER diagrams. Use tools like Object Role Modelling, SBVR, RuleML and other formal methods for recording rule sets.

Comment: Right, right. I should have said a relational database model, using constraints and other tools available, such as views (including materialized) and virtual columns.

Comment: Thanks - you've helped put me on the right trail. I'm using Oracle, which does not at the moment have assertions, so the way to go seems to be using materialized views. Here's one link to check out. There are more: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4233459000346171405

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you realize this, but just to set the stage: In relational database terminology, we normally talk about relationships being 1:1, 1:M, or M:M. There is a fundamental difference in how they work. A 1:1 relationship requires posting a foreign key to one table in the other table. It could be in either table. A 1:M requires posting a foreign key in the "many" table that points to the one. A M:M requires creating a new table, with each record in the relationship table having one pointer to each of the "main" tables.

So: If you say that there are always, for example, exactly 4 rooms per suite in our apartment complex, we might say that's not a general 1:M relationship but a more specific 1:4. But in terms of how we store the data in the RDB, we store it as a 1:M. Each "room record" has a pointer to the "suite record". As far as the DB structure is concerned, it's still 1:M. We can add constraints in DB triggers or in code to enforce that the number must always be exactly 4, but this doesn't affect the DB structure.

On ERDs, where such a constraint is important, some DB designers write the number next to the "many" symbol attaching to the DB entity. Like write "4" if there must be exactly 4.

Note that enforcing exact numbers or minimums can be tricky. It's one thing to say that in real life, everyone has exactly 2 parents. It's another to make this a requirement of our database design. That means that we can't add a "person" record unless we add both his parents at the same time. So either the data entry screen must have fields for all the data about the person himself and also for both of his parents, or we must add dummy records of some sort until we get around to filling in the parent data. And in this example, if the parents are the same record type as the person -- if we were making a genealogy database, say --  then we couldn't add parents without adding the parents' parents, and the parents' parents' parents, and ... where would it stop? There has to be some provision for saying that we're only going to trace this so far back, that beyond that we don't know or don't have time to enter more data now, or at least that when we get to Adam and Eve, that they don't have parents.

I should acknowledge that in some cases, if there are not only a specific number of related records but that they are also distinct in some way, we might create separate pointers for each. For example, instead of saying that each person has two parents, i.e. a 1:M relationship with M=2, we might say that each person has a mother and a father, i.e. two 1:1 relationships. Personally I rarely do this because it usually makes queries and indexing more difficult. Instead of getting both parents by looking at parent_id, we have to examine both mother_id and father_id. If we want to index one we probably want to index the other. If the number is more than 2 or 3, and thus queries have to examine many pointer fields, it's easy for a programmer to miss you, for example, to check pointers 1, 2, 3, 5, and 6 but forget to include 4. Of if someday we decide the maximum is no longer 6 but 7, now every query has to be updated to add a check on pointer #7, and if there are many queries, somebody is going to miss one, and it will be a tricky bug to find because everything will work as long as records have only 6 and not 7, etc.

BTW constraints like "number of rooms must be equal to number of children owner has" are tricky. I'm guessing that's an example you just make up off the top of your head, but it's the kind of trap that's easy to fall into when you're setting specific numbers. Maybe in your family each child has his own bedroom, but in lots of families children have to share a room. Or in the other direction, lots of families have spare bedrooms that they keep for guests. I recall working on a system for medical insurance years ago where they built in a limit of 8 children for each family, because somebody thought, who would ever have more than 8 children? But of course there are families with more than 8 children, and when we got one, the system failed.